# Is there a standard place for the Owner Information on an Android phone?

Tags: security, settings

I found an lost Android phone - is there a standard place on Android phones for owner information so I can contact the person who lost it?

Answer (score 5):

If you go to Settings > Accounts & sync settings, you should be able to see their gmail address and possibly Facebook. You can probably contact them through one of those.

Answer (score 2):

Settings / About Phone / Status shows the device's phone number. Call it and leave a message. Maybe the owner will check their voicemail from home.

Or call people in the contact list, especially ones that show recent history. "Your buddy lost a phone..."

Or call the carrier and tell them you found the phone. They will be able to contact the phone's owner and relay your contact information.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a standard place for Android phone users to set their owner information:

Menu -> Settings -> Security - > Owner Information

There is also a checkbox that makes this information show up on the lock screen.

There is an [article about it at CNET](http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57565765-285/set-android-owner-info-to-help-recover-a-lost-smartphone/) with this useful screenshot:

[image: owner information screenshot]
<sub>(source: [cbsistatic.com](http://asset3.cbsistatic.com/cnwk.1d/i/tim/2013/01/24/Owner_info_lock_screen.png))</sub>